# Java client-server chat application: Weird problems with communication

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, chat

I am making a chat application in Java using sockets.I am getting some weird problems that I have never encountered before. First of all, the server class:

Here is my server class.Please forgive me if I have provided unneeded code, but seeing the nature of my problems, I want to give you guys the complete information.

Server class:

```
public class Server implements Runnable
{   
    private final static int port=8000;
    private static Set<Socket> socs=new HashSet<>();
    private static Thread t1;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static PrintWriter ps;
    private static Socket socketClient;
    private static String message;
    private static HashSet<String> users=new HashSet<>();
    private static HashMap<Socket,String> socket_id=new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String,String> id_name=new HashMap<>();

public Server()
{
    try {

        ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true)
        {System.out.println("Waiting for connections...");
        socketClient=socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to user at: "+socketClient.getInetAddress());
        socs.add(socketClient);
        t1=new Thread(this);
        t1.start();     //to receive data

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//registration for the client
public void registration(String name,String id) throws IOException
{   
if(users.contains(name))
    {
        ps=new PrintWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream());
         ps.println("duplicate"+"\n");
         ps.flush();
    }
    else
     {
    users.add(name);
    socket_id.put(socketClient,id);
    id_name.put(id,name);
    }
}

    public void run() {
    int count=0;
    try {
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
        do
        {
        message=br.readLine();
        if(count==0)
        {
            UUID id=UUID.randomUUID();
            String id_client=id.toString();
            registration(message.substring(0,message.indexOf(':')),id_client);
            count++;
        }
        for(Socket s:socs)
            {
            ps=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            ps.println(message+"\n");
            ps.flush();
            }
        }while(br.readLine()!=null);
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {   
        System.out.println("A user left");


    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Server server=new Server();
    }


}
```

Here are the send and receive functions of my client class:

```
private void send_data()  {

    if(textField.getText().length()!=0)
    {   if(textField.getText().equals("!clear")) //command to clear the chat histroy
        {
        textArea.setText("");
        textField.setText("");
        }
        else
        {   
        ps.println(this.name+": "+textField.getText()+"\n");
        ps.flush();
        }
    }


}


public  void receive_data(){
    try {
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        do
        {   String message=br.readLine();
            if(message.length()!=0)
            console(message);
        }while(br.readLine()!=null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

//this function checks for duplicate username.

```
public void check() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    if(b.readLine().equals("duplicate"))
    {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username taken");
        socket.close();
        b.close();
        dispose();
        new Login().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Now, the problems:

1.When the very first client connects, everything goes fine.The message is displayed to the console as it is expected.

2.When the second user joins, the 1st user cannot send any messages to the server.The latest client runs smoothly, but all the clients connected before it simply cannot send any messages to the server.Or maybe the server is not relaying the messages to them.

3.Whenever a user is told that the username is already taken and is sent back to the login screen, the chat history of all other clients starts showing null.

4.The very first message that the client sends to the server is not displayed on the chat history.From the second message onward, everything runs fine, until any other clients connect.

Please help and thanks in advance.This problem has been bugging me for quite some time now and I cannot debug it, despite many attempts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Socket socketClient;
```

The problem is here. This data item should not be static, and it should not be in the `Server` class at all. It should be in another class, typically a `Runnable`, that is instantiated per accepted client and used as the basis for the corresponding thread.

Same goes for the associated streams, and any other per-client state.

There isn't actually any good reason for any of these non-final data items to be static. Don't make things static unless you know why.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.